# How to dynamically build an option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, dropdown

I have a dropdown list I need to populate with jquery as the list contents will change. I found the basis for the following code on this site. But it is coded to run a set number of items. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3euxxct/1/). You can see if the button is clicked the list contents change. But the list is read from a database and might have 1 item or a hundred. So I added a loop to read through the list and add it to the options list but no matter what I tried it failed. My last attempt is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v3euxxct/2/).

My question is how to change from this:

```
    var options = [ 
        {text: cars[0], value: 1},
        {text: cars[1], value: 2},
        {text: cars[2], value: 3}
        ];
```

to something like this:

```
    var options '';       
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i) {        
       options =  
         {text: cars[i], value: i},
       ;        
     } 
     options = [ + options + ];
```

Here is the code from my first jsfiddle:

```
    <script> 
    var getlist = function() {

    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    var options '';       
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i) {        
       options =  
         {text: cars[i], value: i},
       ;        
     } 
     options = [ + options + ];


        $("#v_make").replaceOptions(options);
    }         

    $('#button').click(getlist);

    (function($, window) {
      $.fn.replaceOptions = function(options) {
        var self, $option;

        this.empty();
        self = this;

        $.each(options, function(index, option) {
          $option = $("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", option.value)
            .text(option.text);
          self.append($option);
        });
      };
    })(jQuery, window)
    </script>

    <select id="v_make">
    <option>start</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the building of the options by passing the `cars` array to your function:

```
 var getlist = function() {
   var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
   $("#v_make").replaceOptions(cars);
 }
 $('#button').click(getlist);

 (function($, window) {
   $.fn.replaceOptions = function(options) {
     var self, $option;

     this.empty();
     self = this;

     $.each(options, function(index, option) {
       $option = $("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", index)
         .text(option);
       self.append($option);
     });
   };
 })(jQuery, window)
```

An updated JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisuae/15zn46d8/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;

  $('#addBtn').on('click', function() {
  
    $('<option>').val(x).text(y).appendTo('#select1');

    x++
    y++

  });



})
```

```html
<select id="select1" style="width:100%;">

<option value="0" selected>(Please select an option)</option>
</select>
<button id="addBtn">Add</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```